# canvas shadow with globalCompositeOperation[ destination-out ]

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

..Hi there, After a long gap,i again got the opportunity to work with JavaScript and canvas.

here i am trying to draw, transparent image using canvas [ **globalCompositeOperation** ] helps me alot,
i got success on draw image[img1] and removed a overlapped part of image[ img2 ].

***search alot but failed :***  Wanna try to drop shadow on output of canvas,look like below,

[image]

Please check out and give me your valuable suggestion OR solution.

```js
$('.bg').one("load", function() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canva'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    img1 = $('.bg')[0],
    img2 = $('.bgover')[0];

  context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  context.beginPath();
  context.drawImage(img2, 10, 10);
  context.closePath();
  //drop shadow -> Doesn't work
  context.shadowBlur = 5;
  context.shadowOffsetX = 10;
  context.shadowOffsetY = 10;
  context.shadowColor = "black";


});
```

```css
body {
  background: #E7FF00
}
.bg {
  background: url() center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class='bg' src="http://www.qdtricks.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/hd-wallpapers-for-mobile.jpg" style='display:none'>

<img class='bgover' src="http://spotremoval.coit.com/sites/spotremoval.coit.com/files/styles/stain_sidebar/public/Feces%20Stain%20Removal%20-%20SPOT%20REMOVAL%20GUIDE.png?itok=j6f96IHQ" style='display:none'>


<canvas id="canva" width="400" height="400" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `dropShadow` function that has the desired effect.

```js
$('.bg').one("load", function() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canva'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    img1 = $('.bg')[0],
    img2 = $('.bgover')[0];

  context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
  context.save();
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  context.drawImage(img2, 10, 10);
  context.restore();

  dropShadow(canvas, "red", 5, 2, 2);
  
});

// This function draws the image to left of canvas
// leaving only the shadow then draws the shadow in the
// empty space.
function dropShadow(can, color, blur, offsetX, offsetY) {
  var s_can = document.createElement('canvas');
  var s_ctx = s_can.getContext('2d');
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  var w = can.width;
  var h = can.height;
  s_can.width = w;
  s_can.height = h;
  s_ctx.shadowBlur = blur;
  s_ctx.shadowColor = color;
  s_ctx.shadowOffsetX = w;
  s_ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
  s_ctx.drawImage(can, 0, 0, w, h,-w,0,w,h);
  
  ctx.save();
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
  ctx.drawImage(s_can, offsetX, offsetY);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #E7FF00
}
.bg {
  background: url() center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class='bg' src="http://www.qdtricks.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/hd-wallpapers-for-mobile.jpg" style='display:none'>

<img class='bgover' src="http://spotremoval.coit.com/sites/spotremoval.coit.com/files/styles/stain_sidebar/public/Feces%20Stain%20Removal%20-%20SPOT%20REMOVAL%20GUIDE.png?itok=j6f96IHQ" style='display:none'>


<canvas id="canva" width="400" height="400" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Inner shadow with destination-out & source-atop**

This is my solution. Load the image then create a copy with a 2D context so it can be drawn to. Then create a second image a little bigger to accommodate the shadow, offsets, and blur. Make it an inverted mask with comp `destination-out`. Set the original image's shadow settings. Then draw the mask image on top with comp `source-atop`

Now the image has the shadow and can be draw where you want it.

The function innerShadow(image,col,offX,offY,blur) does the work. Code is commented so enjoy :)

```js
/** CanvasCtx.js begin **/
var canvas = document.getElementById("canV"); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
/** CanvasCtx.js end **/

// copies an image adding the 2d context
function copyImage(img){
    var image = document.createElement("canvas");  
    image.width = img.width;
    image.height = img.height; 
    image.ctx = image.getContext("2d"); 
    image.ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    return image;
}

// creates a blank image with 2d context
var createImage = function(w,h){
    var image = document.createElement("canvas");  
    image.width = w;
    image.height =h; 
    image.ctx = image.getContext("2d"); 
    return image;
}  

// load an image from URL. Create a editable copy and then 
// call the function ready
var loadImage = function(url,ready){
    function onload(){
        this.removeEventListener("load",onload);
        image = copyImage(this);
        ready(image);
    }
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    image.addEventListener("load",onload);
}


function innerShadow(image,shadowCol,offX,offY,blur){
    var mx, my, img1; 
    // create a mask image, with pixel alpha the invers of original
    // Needs to be bigger so that the shadow is consistant at edges
    img1 = createImage(image.width+Math.abs(offX)+blur,image.height+Math.abs(offY)+blur);
    // set the shadow colur to requiered but only for alising the edge
    img1.ctx.fillStyle = shadowCol;
    img1.ctx.fillRect(0,0,img1.width,img1.height);  // fill the mask
    img1.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";  // remove dest pixels
    mx = img1.width/2- image.width/2;  // recalculate offsets
    my = img1.height/2- image.height/2;
   // draw it 3 times to remove the slight alpha edge bleading
    img1.ctx.drawImage(image,mx,my);  // cut out the images shape from mask
    img1.ctx.drawImage(image,mx,my);  // cut out the images shape from mask
    img1.ctx.drawImage(image,mx,my);  // cut out the images shape from mask

    // set up shadow settings
    image.ctx.shadowColor = shadowCol;
    image.ctx.shadowOffsetX = offX;
    image.ctx.shadowOffsetY = offY;
    image.ctx.shadowBlur = blur;
    // draw the mask with the shadow on original image 
    image.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop"; // only visible pixels
    image.ctx.drawImage(img1,-mx,-my);  // draw the shadow
}


// clear the canvas
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
// load and add shadow. 
var imageWithInnerShadow;
var shadowOffX = 10;
var shadowOffY = 10;
var shadowBlur = 10;
var shadowCol = "Black";
// load the image
loadImage("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jafta.png",function(img){
    // add the shadow
    innerShadow(img,shadowCol,shadowOffX,shadowOffY,shadowBlur);
    ctx.drawImage(img,20,20); // show that it worked
    imageWithInnerShadow = img; // hold the image for use 
})
```

```css
.canC { width:500px;  height:500px;}
```

```html
<canvas class="canC" id="canV" width=500 height=500></canvas>
```